# Azure easytable UpdateAsync not working but InsertAsync is

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a list of orders in a Azure Easy Table in Azure App Services.

When i want to change a object in the list i change them in the app and then try and call: `await CloudOrders.UpdateAsync(obj);`

However this throws a exception "Invalid column name 'Parm8MinMax4'"

The strange thing is that I can delete the object and then insert it again using the following code, and that does not throw a exception.

```
 await CloudOrders.DeleteAsync(obj);
 obj.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 await CloudOrders.InsertAsync(obj);
```

This works I just don't like it because I risk that it deletes the order and then something goes wrong in inserting it again.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When making an **insert** request, **an ID must not be specified** in the data being passed to the Azure Mobile Apps instance. If the insert request contains an ID a `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` will be thrown.

When making an **update** request, an **ID must be specified** so that the Azure Mobile Apps instance can identify the data to be updated. This ID value is stored in the `obj.ID` property. If the update request doesn't contain an ID there is no way for the Azure Mobile Apps instance to determine the data to be updated, and so a `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` will be thrown.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/azure).

Comment: Hello Joey, I made a silly mistake where Parm8MinMax4 was in the local object but not a column in the Easy Table.  Turns out that you can create a new object in a Easy Table from a bigger object than the table but you can not update the table then after.

Comment: So, you still could not update now? And have you update with a specified Id?